# Android service needs to periodically access internet

Tags: android-service

I need to access the internet periodically (every 5 minutes or so) to update a database with a background service.  I have tried the following using Android 8 or 9:

1. Use a boot receiver to start a JobService.
2. In onStartJob of the class that extends JobService, create a LocationListener and request a single location update.
3. Have onStartJob schedule the job again to run in 5-10 minutes.
4. Return true from onStartJob.
5. In the OnLocationChanged of the LocationListener, write to a local file, and start a thread to make a PHP request to update the database.

Everything works fine while the underlying process is running.  When the process dies, the service keeps periodically updating the local file, but the the URLConnection.getResponseCode() now throws an exception -  java.net.ConnectionException: failed to connect to ...

Is there a way to get around this using the above approach?  If not, how can I have a background service access the internet even after the underlying process dies?